# Organizing Channels

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a bot that sets up the server for you when the command !setup is input. I have got to the stage at which the bot creates all of the roles and channels. However, I now need the bot to organize the channels and place text/voice channels inside category channels and move them to the correct position.

```
message.guild.createChannel('server-tests', {
        type: 'text',
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can define the `position` and `parent` properties of a channel when you create it (see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelData)).
- You can use the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (async context needed) to create the channels in order.

```js
try {
  const generalCategory = await message.guild.createChannel('General Stuff', {
    type: 'category',
    position: 3
  });

  await message.guild.createChannel('general-chat', {
    type: 'text',
    parent: generalCategory
  });
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to use await in async context as I do not know what it is.

Comment: Check out the provided documentation via the hyperlink.

Comment: If the code is inside your client's `message` event, declare the callback as async (it should look like `async message => {` or `async function(message) {`). Otherwise, the most relevant function of the scope should be declared similarly.

Comment: wow. :D that is the reason none of my stuff has been working. I didn't realise I had to set the entire command to async. Thank you very much